# Read data from image

Tags: node.js, ocr

I have to a requirement of uploading an image and fetching the text written in that image in text format. The image will be of a business card which i will get from the mobile app. 
I have do it using node js. I tried using ocr npm but i am getting error while installing ocr as dependency, i.e.

```
$ npm install ocr
> ref@1.3.5 install E:\node_modules\ref
> node-gyp rebuild


E:\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node 
"C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-
lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild 
)  else (node 
"C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel 
build, please add the "/m" switch.
E:\node_modules\ref\build\binding.vcxproj(20,3): error MSB4019: The imported 
project "E:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the 
path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on 
disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: 
`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe` failed with exit 
code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit 
(C:\Users\Hello\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-
gyp\lib\build.js:258:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit 
(internal/child_process.js:198:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 6.2.9200
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" 
"C:\\Users\\Hello\\AppData\\Roaming\\npm\\node_modules
\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN my_actionhero_project@0.1.0 No repository field.
npm WARN my_actionhero_project@0.1.0 No license field.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! ref@1.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the ref@1.3.5 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional 
logging output above.
```

Is there any way to fix this issue or any other node module which i can use to read text from image?

Comment: Have you installed the dependencies for your OS as mentioned here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ocr#windows-64-bit ?

Comment: yes i have installed all the dependencies.

Comment: It seems like you don't have visual studio tools installed. http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

Comment: i have visual studio code installed

Comment: That is your editor or IDE. Visual studio build tools are what you require to compile and build your dependencies in this case.

Comment: I tried installing it but it is giving me error says ".net framework installed on this machine do not meet the minimum required version 4.5.1".  So do i have to install .NET framework as well?

Comment: Is there any other option to read the data from image which will have less dependencies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same error while installing ocr in Ubuntu. According to me, It is OS specific error. When I tried to install ocr in MAC OS using "npm i ocr", It is installed successfully. So you can try this.